# Unknown compiler option 'noImplicitOverride'

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, tsconfig

In angular 13 app with Typescript 4.5.2 , I am getting an error in the tsconfig.json file . "noImplicitOverride" is set to true and gives "Unknown compiler option 'noImplicitOverride'.ts".
I have set it to false and still get the error.

```
{
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"noImplicitOverride": true ,
"noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es2017",
"module": "es2020",
"lib": [
  "es2020",
  "dom"
]
```

Comment: have you restarted your angular dev server?

Comment: @danday74 yes I did but didn't work

Comment: download : JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly in visual studio code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this I had to install the NuGet package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild in my Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. I rolled back to Typescript 4.4.2 and the error disappeared.